# npx react-native run-android doesn't start emulator and doesn't run if emulator is running

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, react-native

I've created a new project using react-native 0.63
and when I run on ios simulator everything works fine
but when try to run it on android, it does not work and gives me this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Volumes/SSD2/developer/MyProject/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

i install react-native like
[react-native Setting up](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

and this is the output from my react-native doctor

```
✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 29.0.2
 ✖ ANDROID_HOME

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI

Errors:   2
Warnings: 0
```

and if I run npx react-native start then the application runs from android studio smoothly.

Edit
if i run project from terminal source .bash_profile

emulator start but project not run

```
"--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 5194 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
env: sh\r: No such file or directory

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
env: sh\r: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc (if you are using zsh then ~/.zprofile or ~/.zshrc) config file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Type source $HOME/.bash_profile for bash or source $HOME/.zprofile to load the config into your current shell. Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been set by running echo $ANDROID_HOME and the appropriate directories have been added to your path by running echo $PATH.

Please make sure you use the correct Android SDK path. You can find the actual location of the SDK in the Android Studio "Preferences" dialog, under Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK.

References:

- https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup 3. Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Comment: but am sure 
i set ANDROID_HOME in file: bash_profile

Comment: what do you get when you run ` echo $ANDROID_HOME` in the terminal?

Comment: i get just  ( ANDROID_HOME )

Comment: Make sure you have the dollar symbol at the start like `$ANDROID_HOME`.

Comment: if set dollar symbol don't return any thing

Comment: That means it's not set. If you think it is set then try open a new terminal window and run it again. That way the new window will start with the new environment variables you set.

Comment: lock this is my .bash_profile  =====> 
   
export ANDROID_HOME=/Volumes/SSD2/developer/sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

Comment: Ok so when you run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it should output `/Volumes/SSD2/developer/sdk ` if it's not then you need to run `source .bash_profile` or open a new terminal window.

Comment: good after write `source .bash_profile`
and test `echo $ANDROID_HOME`
output `/Volumes/SSD2/developer/sdk `

but i try to run project still not working  and give me same error

Comment: Are you running `npx react-native run-android` from a new terminal window?

Comment: nice i try to run project from same terminal then emulator open but project not running

Comment: That's progress at least. Do you get any errors in the terminal when running the project?

Comment: i get this =>
`info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 5194 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
env: sh\r: No such file or directory

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
env: sh\r: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like it still can't find the Android SDK. Maybe try reboot your machine. That sometimes helps after installing the Android sdk.

Comment: Ok i will restart

Comment: Exactly  the problem from Android Sdk 100%
Thank you very much  proooo :D

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable**

The React Native tools require some environment variables to be set up in order to build apps with native code.

Go to Home directory and show hidden files then add the following lines to your `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc` (if you are using bash terminal, then `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`) config file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Run `source ~/.zprofile` or `source ~/.zshrc`  (or `source ~/.bash_profile`  or `source ~/.bashrc` for bash) in your root terminal to load the config into your current shell. Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been set by running echo $ANDROID_HOME and the appropriate directories have been added to your path by running echo $PATH.

Restart your system if still error persists.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I move the code from Windows to Mac os.

then just do

1. On the android folder (cd android)

then run the below code

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

2. then run

   ./gradlew clean
3. then just run the below cmd

   npx react-native run-android

Comment: I wanted to try this in Github Codespaces, it didnt work.